# Jquery Tablesorter Plugin not funtioning properly with AjaxToolkit Accordion

Tags: c#, jquery, accordion, tablesorter, scroller

Am developing an ASP webform project and having some difficulties with JQuery tablesorter Plugin.
I applied the plugin to an ASP Gridview control which is in an Ajax Accordion. Am not sure what the problem is but the table doesn't display fully on the first page Load. Your help and feedback ae highly appreciated

See Pic on first page Load:
[Table cannot load fully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mb0N.png)

But after every postback or after i adjust the browser (Minimize/maximize) then the table loads fully.

see pic:
[Full Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSYHq.png)

//Js code for tablesorter

```
function BindTablesorter() {
    
$('#gv_MoeglicheEmailverteiler').tablesorter({

        theme: 'jui',
        showProcessing: true,
        headerTemplate: '{content} {icon}',
        stickyHeaders: "tablesorter-stickyHeader",
        resizable: true,

        widgets: ['uitheme','zebra', 'filter', 'scroller'],

        widgetOptions: {
            scroller_upAfterSort: true,
            scroller_jumpToHeader: true,
            scroller_height: 450,
            scroller_fixedColumns: 2,
            scroller_addFixedOverlay: false,
            scroller_rowHighlight: 'hover',
            scroller_barWidth: null
          
        },

    });   

}

$(document).ready(function () {

   BindTablesorter(); 
});
```

// Markup for Gridview

```
<ajaxToolkit:AccordionPane ID="AccPEmailverteiler" runat="server">
  <Header><u>Emailverteiler</u></Header>
    <Content>
       <asp:UpdatePanel ID="up_EmailVerteilerOne" runat="server">
         <ContentTemplate>
           <script type="text/javascript">
           Sys.Application.add_load(BindTablesorter);
           </script>
           <asp:GridView ID="gv_MoeglicheEmailverteiler" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" 
           AutoGenerateColumns="false" BorderColor="#DEBA84" BackColor="Silver" HeaderStyle Height="40px" OnPreRender="gv_MoeglicheEmailverteiler_PreRender"             HorizontalAlign="Center" CellPadding="3" CssClass="tablesorter">
<Columns>                
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Reihe" ItemStyle-Width="200px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">   
   <ItemTemplate>
    <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>   
   </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="gruppenname" HeaderText="Gruppenname" NullDisplayText="n/a" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="250px"/>                           
  <asp:BoundField DataField="standort" HeaderText="Standort" NullDisplayText="n/a" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="250px"/>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="beschreibung" HeaderText="Beschreibung" NullDisplayText="n/a" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="250px"/>             
  <asp:BoundField DataField="genehmigt" HeaderText="Genehmigt" NullDisplayText="n/a" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="250px"/>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="zielobjekt" HeaderText="ZielObjekt" NullDisplayText="n/a" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="250px"/>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="ACTION_CHECKED" HeaderText="Action_Checked" NullDisplayText="n/a" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="250px" />
  <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="300px"  HeaderText="Action" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
  <ItemTemplate>
   <asp:CheckBox ID="cb_CheckOneMoglicheverteilerRow" runat="server" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" class="checkboxClass" AutoPostBack="true" onclick = "Check_Click(this);" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox_CheckChanged"/>
  </ItemTemplate>        
  </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
<HeaderStyle ForeColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" BackColor="#CCCC00"></HeaderStyle>                       
</asp:GridView>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</Content>
</ajaxToolkit:AccordionPane>
```

Comment: try with setTimeout(function(){   BindTablesorter(); },1200)

Comment: Thanks @Negi, i tried but didn't get the expected result. I think its has to with the widgets (especially the scroller) or the entire table size. Because when i put the table outside of the Accordion, the table  gets to large that it doesnt fit on page. am thinking the Accordion is hindering the table from rendering properly, but outside of the Accordion, the table is rendered too large/big and doesnt fit on my page as well